# Adsense wouldn't approve my reactjs app, is there any work around?

Tags: reactjs, adsense

I have a reactjs application on the web with good traffic, but anytime i submit an adsense application, my website gets rejected because its a single page application, meanwhile i have seen react-adsense and some other such libraries for reactjs apps, so i believe there could be a work around. I'll really appreciate your thoughts and ideas.

Comment: Maybe try searching on universal, aka isomorphic, react frameworks which do server side and client side rendering so your site isn't necessarily considered a SPA. As a bonus, this also helps your site with SEO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Adsense doesn't deny applications due to them being single-page. It should give you a reason behind your denial, likely not enough content or detail.

You should look at your app and think "could I fit ads here?" if yes, review your app and judge the amount of content you have. If no, reconsider your design to better fit placing ads in your app.

Comment: The link posted requires action or information to be given to be able to see the content.
Please elaborate your post and give it another shot.